# Highmaps in React

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to use HighMaps with react, going through different docs and examples I achieved to show the Title, the Legend and the navigation button (+ and -).

The problem is that I can't show the map if I pick the data from a call to an API (call to API>Data inside an array) instead if I paste the link to the API in the browser and save the result in a file and then import the file in my project and use it as the variable everything is fine,

So is there any way to display the map directly from a call to the API instead of saving it into a file and then import it in the project?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

useEffect(() => {
    const apiCall = async () => {
        let result = null;
        await axios.get(`linkToTheAPI`)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    result = response.data;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (!error.response) {
                    alert("Unable to connect to web service");
                }
                else if (error.response.status === 401) {
                    alert("Unauthorized User");
                }
                else if (error.response.status === 500) {
                    alert("Internal Server Error");
                }
            });
        return result;
    }
    const apiCallandSetData = async () => {
        let res = await apiCall();
        if (res)
        {
            setDataFromApi(res);
            console.log(dataFromApi);
            setMapOptions({chart: {map: res}});   
        }
    }
    apiCallandSetData();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
},[])

let mapOptions = {
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: null,
        map: dataFromApi
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        minRange: 0.1
    },

    yAxis: {
        minRange: 0.1
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        animation: false,
        allowPointSelector: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        keys: ['code_hasc', 'value'],
        joinBy: 'code_hasc',
        name: '',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#AFE8FF',
                borderColor: '#2A93FC'
            },
            select: {
                color: '#AFE8FF',
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
        }, 
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
        }
    }]
}
```

`dataFromApi` is the variable that stores the result of the call 
if I put the `file` instead of `dataFromApi` everything works fine

Comment: Do you use the official Highcharts React wrapper? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react Notice that it is advised to set the chart config as an State which could be updated after getting your data from the API.

Comment: If I set the mapOptions as state works, thank you

Comment: I added the answer to your question - please accept it - it could be useful for the other users in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments - using the official Highcharts React wrapper and defining the config as a State resolved the issue.

API: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react